# spry menu bar display issues on firefox and chorome working fine on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site, [www.stprc.com](http://www.stprc.com), and I have used spry menu bar - it was working fine before, but now some menu items backgrounds are not displaying and on hover shows the text only. Sometimes they start blinking as well. It happens with the 3 menu items which are not showing currently, rest are appearing fine. This is happening on both Chrome and Firefox, whereas on IE everything works fine.

I have no clue as to why this is happening. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is ignoring the background-image you are setting (SpryMenuBarDown.gif), so it looks how you expect. The background image is screwing up the menu, so in browsers that are processing your background-image, it is screwing up the menu. Remove `background-image(SpryMenuBarDown.gif)` and it should work in modern browsers.